# setting up a maven project in Juno Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, maven, dependencies

I recently upgraded my Eclipse to Juno and am struggling with the way maven dependencies are handled.

I installed the m2e plugin.  Still, many of my projects started complaining about libraries missing as if the dependencies specified in the pom were completely ignored.  This happened despite right-clicking on the project, selecting Configure --> Convert to Maven project, which seems to be the replacement for what used to be "Maven --> Enable dependencies" before.  When I looked at the Maven dependencies under the project directory, there were many fewer dependencies listed than in my pom.

Running a maven compile on the command line outside of Eclipse allowed my project to build and after selecting Maven --> Update project, I was able to see the dependencies added or removed accordingly to what I specified in the pom.xml.

Bottom line: maven dependencies seem to work now but I had to do some combination of operations I didn't think should have been needed:
- Configure -> Convert to Maven project
- Maven -> Update dependencies
- Run maven outside of Eclipse

To get everything to work when with previous versions of Eclipse, all I had to do was Maven -> enable dependencies.  What is the equivalent of this in Juno, i.e. what is the correct way of setting up juno Eclipse to handle properly a maven project?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have been using Juno for a while now and the reliable way to solve Maven dependencies from within Eclipse after importing a project that is maven based is simply:

1. Configure --> Convert to Maven project
2. Maven --> Update project

Running Maven outside of Eclipse doesn't seem to help.

I am not sure why these two steps are now required when they were not before with previous version of Eclipse (at least, two steps were not needed before for sure).

Running

```
mvn -Declipse.workspace=<path-to-eclipse-workspace> eclipse:add-maven-repo
```

outside of Eclipse has brought me the problems I described in my comment to the other answer.

Answer (score 0):

On a Mac running Windows under Parallels Desktop on OS X?  This similar discussion may solve your problem: [intellij - java: Cannot find JDK '1.7' for module](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14278936/intellij-java-cannot-find-jdk-1-7-for-module)

Comment: No. Regular Eclipse for mac running on mac, but thanks for the link.