# intellij import existing eclipse android project failed

Tags: java, intellij-idea

After importing i got that error in compilation:

```
java: Cannot find JDK '<unknown>' for module 'CallsFreeCalls'
```

Also i can't see Android UI Designer inside JI

here what i have inside Project settings:

[image]

i have two choices there, but if i change it, nothing happened :(

this is approving that android designer enabled:

[image]

project SDK:

[image]

platform settings SDKs:

[image]

a building problem was solved by adding into platform setting/SDKs Java 1.6 sdk. But i still don't see Android UI Designer anywhere. Project now builded as well, but JI showing error in XML layout files (not actually repeat while building is done):
[image]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try the following: select that module in the Project tool window (on the left), and press F4 on it. This will open the `Project Structure` dialog. Make sure to select your module and the `Dependencies` tab as shown on the picture:

[image: Setting up the modules SDK dependency]

Set your SDK from the `Module SDK` drop-down.

As for the UI Designer: check if the Android Designer plugin is enabled in Settings/Plugins.

Comment: i was try to do u solution before and that was not help. please review my updated question.

Comment: Also try checking on the same dialog if the Project SDK is properly set, and take a look at the "SDKs" entry under the Plattform Settings as well. If that doesn't help try to find similar questions like [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5271182/how-do-i-set-up-intellij-idea-for-android-applications) and [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14278936/intellij-java-cannot-find-jdk-1-7-for-module).

Comment: tnx for suggestion, can you please check also updated question (i will don't have designer inside)

Comment: I'm affraid I can't help much with the Designer issue, as I haven't used it myself. A couple of tipps though: read through the related docs in [IntelliJ's Help pages](http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/webhelp/designing-layout-of-android-application.html) (also [here](http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/webhelp/designing-layout-of-android-application.html)). If you still don't manage to make it work, it will probably easier to create an Android project from scratch in IDEA, and then copy the sources of the eclipse project manually.