# IntelliJ IDEA - "Imported project refers to unknown jdks JavaSE-1.8" while import Eclipse projects

Tags: java, eclipse, intellij-idea

I tried to import `Eclipse` project to `IntelliJ IDEA`, but I got this error:

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The eclipse project description contains a reference to a "manually" defined JDK (named JavaSE-1.8).

Just go forward and define an SDK for your project within IntelliJ yourself. See [here](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/2017.1/defining-a-jdk-and-a-mobile-sdk-in-intellij-idea.html) for the necessary steps:

> To define a JDK and a mobile SDK in IntelliJ IDEA
>
> Open the Project Structure dialog (e.g. Ctrl+Shift+Alt+S).
>
> In the leftmost pane, under Platform Settings, click SDKs.
>
> Above the pane to the right, click ￼ and select JDK.
>
> In the dialog that opens, select the installation directory of the JDK to be used and click OK.

... (obviously you don't need the Java ME mobile specific things listed in the original link)

Answer (score 1):

[Here they had a similar problem, but with android sdk](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15098688/intellij-import-existing-eclipse-android-project-failed)

You must edit `Project SDK` in `Project Structures > Dependencies` to existing Java JDK