# Error: java: Cannot find JDK 1.7 for module main

Tags: java, linux, intellij-idea, jdk1.7

I am trying to run my tests on Linux and I am getting this error.
I am using centos 6.0
Idea Intellij

Comment: Refer [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14278936/intellij-java-cannot-find-jdk-1-7-for-module) and [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29286714/intellij-java-cannot-find-jdk-1-8)

Comment: what error you are talking about ?

Comment: cannot find JDK 1.7
when I am trying to run a method